# breezejs: dynamically switching between OData and WebAPI

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm facing a bit of a tricky situation here. I have two services that my application needs to access to. One is a pure ODATA service and the other is a WebAPI (with Breeze controller) service.

My application is designed around the AngularJS modules and breeze is injected into two differerent single-instance services :

```
angular.module('domiciliations.services').
   factory('domiciliationService', function (breeze) {

     breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
     //more initialization goes here

     //then query methods go here
}
```

and

```
angular.module('person.services').
   factory('personService', function (breeze) {

    breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ "dataService": "OData" });

     //more initialization goes here

     //then query methods go here
}
```

Now obviously the problem is that once the person service has been instanciated, the domiciliations service then uses OData because the config was overwritten.

So, what is the general approach for tackling this issue ? Is there a way to isolate the config ? 
So far the only way I can think of, is to call the initializeAdapterinstances method each time a query method is called, which is not really desirable.

**EDIT**

As per Jay's recommandation I'm now using DataService. I'm having an error though in ctor.resolve at the line:

```
ds.jsonResultsAdapter = ds.jsonResultsAdapter || ds.adapterInstance.jsonResultsAdapter;
```

ds.adapterInstance is null, therefore this throws an exception. But I don't understand why it's null.

Here's what I've done:

```
var service = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: 'http://localhost:16361/api/mandates',
            adapterName: 'WebApi'
        });
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: service });

//this is the line causing the later exception:

manager.fetchMetadata().then(function () { ... }
```

Did I forget to do something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

The *initializeAdapterInstance* method is really intended to setup the 'default' adapters.

If you need to have multiple adapters and apply them on a per query basis then see the *DataService* documentation especially the 'adapterName' property in the ctor.  You can have two DataServices, one for OData and one for WebApi.  You can then use either for any query via the *EntityQuery.using* method.

```
 var odataDataService = new DataService({
       serviceName: "Foo",
       adapterName: "OData"
 });
 var webApiDataService = new DataService({
       serviceName: "Bar",
       adapterName: "WebApi"
 });

 var query1 = EntityQuery.from(...).where(...);
 var query2 = EntityQuery.from(...).where(...);

 entityManager.executeQuery(query1.using(odataDataService)).then(...)
 entityManager.executeQuery(query2.using(webApiDataService)).then(...)
```

Comment: @@Jay, that sounds good, although I still have to specify at query level which service to use (it'd be better to specify at manager's level, if manager weren't sharing the same breeze instance).  I'm having an error while using this code though, see my updated post. Any idea what's wrong ?

Comment: Not sure what else is going on but in your example above, the EntityManager.fetchMetadata call does not take a 'dataService' as an arg. A MetadataStore.fetchMetadata call does (see the api docs). Basically, an entityManager has a single 'default' dataService. This default can be changed via an EntityManager.setProperties call. An entityManager has a metadataStore that itself can have metadata from a variety of dataServices.

Comment: I got it to work but I don't understand what's going on. I had to write that line of code before creating the EntityManager :                  breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstances({ "dataService": "WebApi" });
Why do I still need to initialize the default adapter since I'm now using DataService  ?

Comment: Now that I'm using DataService, I'm actually getting an error when calling SaveChanges() :  ReferenceError: « AutoGeneratedKeyType » is undefined
   at Anonymous function (localhost:1502/Scripts/libs/breeze/Adapters/breeze.dataService.webApi.js:184:13)

Comment: AutoGeneratedKeyType.None is used in breeze.dataService.webApi.js but the AutoGeneratedKeyType enum is actually defined in breeze.debug.js. There's something I don't quite get here.

Comment: I'll open a separate issue for this, as it is unrelated to the original